# Create Magento Custom Report Module

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to create custom report in magento. 
How to create a custom report in magento?
Can share link how to create? Because i find very few solution to create to custom report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the few links, which you can go through on creating custom reports in admin :

- http://codegento.com/2011/03/creating-custom-magento-reports/
- http://magentotutorial.in/create-custom-reports-in-magento-admin/
- http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/create-custom-reports-in-magento-admin/
- [Creating new completely custom reports](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/creating-new-completely-custom-reports)
- https://confuzi.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/create-custom-reports-in-magento-admin/

Comment: please update for M2 also