# Magento 2 require to create SQL query for the custom report

Tags: magento2.3, customer-attribute, reports, custom-reports

I would like to generate Magento native report as follows:

[image]

Can anybody provide the SQL query for above table ?

1. Column Name CustomerGender  = customer attribute
2. Column Name Group  = Customer Group native feature
3. Grand Total = Grand total from Sales order table

Went through plenty of the links but got regular simple joins.

[Create Magento Custom Report Module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115495/create-magento-custom-report-module)

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-reports

Comment: Can you try the query and let me know it's perfect for you!

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: let me give a try..!!!

Comment: thank for the answer.. i'm able to get the with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the results using below SQL query.

```
SELECT   eav_attribute_option_value.value as 'Gender', 
                customer_group.customer_group_code as 'Group',
                CONCAT('$', FORMAT(SUM(sales_order.`grand_total`),2)) AS 'Grand total'
FROM `customer_grid_flat`
    LEFT JOIN 
        customer_group ON customer_grid_flat.group_id = customer_group.customer_group_id
    LEFT JOIN
        sales_order ON customer_grid_flat.entity_id = sales_order.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN
        eav_attribute_option_value ON customer_grid_flat.gender = eav_attribute_option_value.option_id

WHERE eav_attribute_option_value.value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY eav_attribute_option_value.value, customer_group_code
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this Query

```
SELECT 
    eav_attribute_option_value.value AS 'Customer gender',
    customer_group.customer_group_code AS 'Group',
    CONCAT('$',
            FORMAT(SUM(sales_order.`grand_total`),
                2)) AS 'Grand total'
FROM
    `customer_entity`
        LEFT JOIN
    sales_order ON customer_entity.entity_id = sales_order.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN
    customer_group ON customer_entity.group_id = customer_group.customer_group_id
        LEFT JOIN
    eav_attribute_option_value ON customer_entity.gender = eav_attribute_option_value.option_id
GROUP BY customer_entity.entity_id
ORDER BY SUM(sales_order.`grand_total`) ASC
```

The final output is
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: `Error in query (1055): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'magento2db.eav_attribute_option_value.value' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`