# Blank custom report magento

Tags: magento-1.7, reports

I using this guide [Creating new completely custom reports](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/creating-new-completely-custom-reports) to do my custom report,
but show blank the the custom report page.
Can help me solve it?

[image: Blank page]

My code same with the guide. Please check at that link.

Comment: Have you added layout file at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout ? If yes then add code of this file and your module config.xml code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Reports>Refresh Statistics then on the right side of page at the top in the dropdown select Refresh Lifetime Statistics, then select all and refresh. Try running your report again.

Comment: still blank, can help me check the guide code can run?