# Help creating custom report and debugging blank page

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, debugging

I'm trying to create a custom report using the guide here...
[Creating new completely custom report](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/creating-new-completely-custom-reports)

I created it EXACTLY as described. The new report shows up in the dropdown for Reports as it should, but I only get a blank page (besides the header and footer). Even if there wasn't any data for the report, I think I should still get a empty grid.

I added logging to all the functions in all the files under Block directory, but nothing is getting logged. Example, in `Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule_Grid`

```
public function __construct() {
    Mage::log("construct()", null, 'Mymodule.log');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('mymoduleGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setSubReportSize(false);
}
```

Not sure where to go to even begin debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem and it was me being stupid. Thought I had all cache turned off, but Blocks HTML output was still enabled. Flushed Magento Cache and everything started working.