# Join table to get the detail of customer, customer ordered item, and the item product

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, grid, sql, select

i'm following this [tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14783/53812) to create the grid for custom report, and to get the collection there's a function which accept the from date and to date like this:

```
public function setDateRange($from, $to) {
       $this->_reset();
       $this->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(array(
                'i' => $this->getTable('sales/order_item')),
                'i.order_id = main_table.entity_id'
                )
            ->where('i.parent_item_id is null')
            ->where("i.created_at BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'")
            ->where('main_table.state = \'complete\'')
            ->columns(array('ordered_qty' => 'count(distinct `main_table`.`entity_id`)'));
      //  uncomment next line to get the query log:
      //  Mage::log('SQL: '.$this->getSelect()->__toString(),null,'query.log');
       return $this;
   }
```

the problem is i need to create a custom collection, to load the customer data, including the product item data which customer already ordered like this:

[image: example]